# hosting multiple websites in the same server

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, web-development, server, nginx

I have a server that has **multiple websites**, when i access one of them by the ip address or domain name it directs me there with no problem,the rest are accessed by a domain name without any problem, i added a new website for Wordpress, when I try accessing it via the domain name there is a problem it is says

> "This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in wordpress.example.com.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"
> Blockquote

**stuff I tried and general details* *

1. my new website is added to in /var/www/sites the directory is called wordpress
2. I edited the configuration file in

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress_website

so that it includes

> server_name example.learning.com;

> root /var/www/sites/wordpress;

3.I also added to **etc/hosts** the following line

> IP-Address example.learning.com

- I only added the IP address and domain name to etc/hosts when the other steps were not working but still it did no fix anything

4.I created a **symlink** in **sites-enabled** directory

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Oct 31 11:13 wordpress_website-> /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress_website

5.when I viewed **nginx logs** I found a few **errors** but I think this one is related to this issue

> 2023/11/29 03:23:23 [error] 286099#286099: *1185 directory index of "/var/www/wordpress_website/" is forbidden, client: 205.210.31.207, server: example123.domainname.net, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example123.domainname.net"

*I just want to point out that the site name in **var/www/sites is called wordpress** not **wordpress_website** which is why I found the previous **error** weird

**Any help** would be appreciated Thank you

Comment: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` is a DNS problem.  What are the DNS records for it?

Comment: It also sounds like your browser is ignoring `/etc/hosts`.  Is DNS over HTTPS (DoH) enabled in your browser?

Comment: First make sure your computer is pointing to the right IP by using the host command.